# How can I display an external website in my PhoneGap app including a own header/footer

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, cordova, external

The title says it all.
My question is, how to display an external website into my webapp with a header or footer.

I tried it with an iFrame, but there is the problem, that i can't go back in history with the backbutton for example, can I?

The second idea i tried is the inAppBrowser, but there is the problem that I cannot use any Phonegap Features and include my own header.

So i need something like an inAppBrowser shown in an iFrame.

I hope you can help me with this question.

Sincerely

Comment: I found a solution. Cross-document messaging is the "magic word".

Here you get an example: [Cross-ducument messaging][1]


  [1]: https://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/getting-access-to-a-phones-camera-from-a-web-page/

Answer (score -1):

check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

if you are willing to implement a back button..